# how to get column names from 2 different table id

Tags: php, select

I have two tables and joined them to one different table

```
1 table named 'rec_dept'
id_dept
id_divisi
nama_dept

2 table named 'rec_divisi'
id_divisi
nama_div

3 joined table named 'rec_divdep'
id_divdep
id_divisi
id_dept
```

How to get `nama_dept` where in the same `id_divisi`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do a `SELECT` query with a `LEFT JOIN` function to get data

```
SELECT a.`nama_dept` FROM `rec_dept` a 
LEFT JOIN `rec_divisi` b 
ON a.`id_divisi` = b.`id_divisi` 
ORDER BY a.`id_divisi` ASC
```

[SELECT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

[LEFT JOIN documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Comment: you welcome man, if the answer was correct please accept it for future people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
SELECT `nama_dept` FROM `rec_dept` WHERE `id_divisi` IN (SELECT `id_divisi` FROM `rec_divdep`);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id_dept, a.id_divisi, a.nama_dept, b.id_divisi, b.nama_div, c.id_divdep, c.id_divisi from rec_divdep as c left join rec_divisi as b on (c.id_divisi = b.id_divisi) left join rec_dept as a on (c.id_divisi = a.id_divisi)
```

what database do you use. I code mine as mysql, basically I condition the three tables that has same id_divisi. I did not test it but I am pretty sure of the logic based on what I understand.

Comment: no problem. you may view some tutorials of sql joins here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp